# how to get selected index row of table using php?

Tags: php, mysql

guy's i need you help.
i dont know how to get selected index row of table for inserting the data.
example. i have table like this. i've thead (no, tanggal, no.polisi, netto) i want to make insert function just for (no and tanggal) only. how to do that with php? i really dont know how to grab the selected index of the table

i hope someone can give me an example `

```
<form name="table_1" id="table_1" class="table_1">
<table id="table_1" class="table_1" cellspacing='0' class="js-serial" border="2">
    <thead>
   <tr>
            <th width="50"><center>No.</center></th>
            <th width="100"><center>Tanggal</center></th>
            <th width="80"><center>No.Polisi</center></th>
            <th width="60"><center>Netto</center></th>

  </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>

  </tbody>
  </table>
  </form></div>
  <div id="kanan" class="btn btn-default">
  <form name="table_2" id="table_2" class="table_2">
<table id="table_2" class="table_2" cellspacing='0' class="js-serial" border="2">
    <thead>
   <tr>
            <th width="50"><center>No.</center></th>
            <th width="100"><center>Tanggal</center></th>
            <th width="80"><center>No.Polisi</center></th>
            <th width="60"><center>Netto</center></th>

  </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>

  </tbody>
  </table>
  </form></div>
  <table>
  <tr>
            <td width=482>Total Keseluruhan Netto :</td>
            <td width=30>
            <input type="text" id="total_netto" class="total_netto" type="text" name="total_netto" size="17"  readonly="readonly" /> </td>

  </tr>
  </table>
```

`

Comment: use php domxpath query.

Comment: i need something like a plugin?

Comment: use jquery to do in easy way.

Comment: i must define the index 1st with jquery then i call that index into php? right?

Comment: in jquery call ajax to get data and append that in  table.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: you can follow this solution on SO.[http://stackoverflow.com/q/36248651/1676023](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36248651/1676023)

Comment: thx a lot.. i've try that and it work